# gulp main-bower-files regular expression filter not working

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gulp, bower

Why is the second array, `bowerFiles`, not filtered to just javascript files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('default', function () {

  var unfiltered = mainBowerFiles(); 
  console.log('unfiltered files:', unfiltered); // 11 FILES

  //var jsRegEx = /js$/i; // tried this way too...
  var jsRegEx = new RegExp('js$', 'i');
  var bowerFiles = mainBowerFiles(jsRegEx);
  console.log('bower files:', bowerFiles); // 11 FILES

});
```

I have tried to mimic what bower-main-files is doing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjjun217/), and it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create a `RegExp` to filter for files with [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files).

Indeed, you can simply pass an array or a string of glob to check only for `.js` files:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  var bowerFiles = mainBowerFiles('**/*.js');
  console.log('bower files: ', bowerFiles);
});
```

If you really want to use the regex, you have to use the `filter` option, you can't directly pass it as an argument:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  var bowerFiles = mainBowerFiles({ filter: new RegExp('.*js$', 'i') });
  console.log('bower files: ', bowerFiles);
});
```

Comment: I am trying this and getting ` Invalid glob argument: [object Object]` `gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js'))`