# Exclude a folder from main-bower-files

Tags: gulp, bower, main-bower-files

How do I filter out an entire folder from the [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files)?

For example, if I'm doing this `mainBowerFiles('**/jquery-validation/**')`, it returns only the files from the `jquery-validation` folder, but I need the opposite.

I've tried `mainBowerFiles('!**/jquery-validation/**')`, however it seems like `!` sign doesn't work in this case. What's wrong with my pattern?

Comment: You should read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749749/gulp-main-bower-files-regular-expression-filter-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to ignore Bower Packages getting picked up by `mainBowerFiles` with adding `overrides: PACKAGE_NAME` to `bower.json`

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "description": "",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    },
    "overrides": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": {
            "ignore": true
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#ignore

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using [filter](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#filter) function:

```
var ignoreJs = ['jquery-validation', ...];

// filter function
function mainBowerFilesFilter(filePath) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ignoreJs.length; i++) {
        if (filePath.indexOf(ignoreJs[i]) !== -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// how to use
mainBowerFiles({ filter: mainBowerFilesFilter })
```